# Android Studio importing project problem, Gradle update, and Gauge Intellij plugin

Tags: android, gradle, intellij-idea, import, gauge

Could anyone help me to solve this problem?

I am learning Android using [Udacity](https://classroom.udacity.com/courses/ud839/lessons/7633778648/concepts/2eef07a4-abb3-448f-8025-8aeb7cf21621).

Once I import the project and press run, I need to update some plugin, Gradle... etc.. According to the prompt message.

However, I still have the following error in Event Log:

> Unable to start Gauge Intellij plugin. Could not find executable in
> `PATH`.
>
> Please make sure Gauge is installed.
>
> If Gauge is installed then set the Gauge executable path in settings
> -> tools -> gauge.

---

Anyone can help me to solve this problem? (Simple English please!)